# How to edge laminate to curved edge?

Tags: shower, laminate-floor, laminate

I have been asked to fit bathroom laminate in our bathroom. I have laid bathroom laminate before, so that holds no fear for me.

Edging laminate is usually one of two options:

- skirting boards are used to hide the edge of the floor
- scotia trim or similar is run round the edge of the wall to hide the edge of the floor

The problem I have is that the shower tray of my bathroom is a 800mm quadrant, and so I will need to edge the floor round this curved edge. How can I do this?

Using scotia trim, I need to find some trim which is flexible enough (so far I haven't found anything) and the tray is fixed in place, and I don't want to have to re-do the plumbing of the waste (as I didn't do it, I don't know how it's all fitted together so taking it apart without damage is tricky).

Comment: So you cannot use a 1/4 round up to the tub that is what I normally use. Ir just calk it.

Comment: I've found that those things snap when trying to accommodate to the curve

Comment: Your use of the word "laminate" had me really confused. To me, "laminate" is a thin sheet of some sort of man-made substance that is adhered to the top of a counter. You're using it to describe trim ("skirting boards", "scotia trim") which is unusual. Technically, I suppose it's correct, since "laminate" means to build up from layers, which is what you're doing, but it's... unusual... Also, please come back to resolve this - did you use one of the answers given? Give it a check mark! If not, write up what you did in your own answer and give yourself a check mark - that will help others learn.

Comment: @FreeMan the flooring type i am using is known it the UK and laminate flooring. As it's made up of laminations of wood/plastic/etc to make a cheap floor covering with a variety of textures and colours..

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I am certainly familiar with laminate flooring, so I guess it's the use of "edging laminate" that threw me, then! You used "edging" where I'd use "trimming" or "trimming out". The difference between British and American when it comes to English, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search for "flexible trim" shows several items that should work. I don't know if they're any good but they're clearly designed to do what you want and there are several to choose from.

Here's one example called [eXtreme® Quickstep Flexible Laminate Floor Beading & Skirting](https://www.amazon.co.uk/eXtreme%C2%AE-Quickstep-Flexible-Laminate-Skirting/dp/B00BEWWV5A/). The photo looks like it matches your description exactly.

[image: eXtreme® Quickstep Flexible Laminate Floor Beading & Skirting]

And there's also something called [Flexible PVC skirting](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Flexible-PVC-skirting-50x15-Baseboard/dp/B06WD5G9GD/) which is taller but equally flexible since it also comes in a roll.

Comment: Yes that is what I am after! I could not find any at my local DIY places. Will get some online when suitable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to cut an inside curve into the laminate so that it fits the contour of the shower tray...

Try this: 
Use a ceramic tiling contour tool. (lots of thin wires in parallel alignment that, when pressed against an irregular shape, take the form of the shape so that you can mark the cut-line accurately.)

Slide the tool horizontally to press it against the lowest surface of the rounded corner of the shower tray. Then place the contour tool on stiff paper and draw the curve. You now have a template for cutting the laminate.
Use the template to draw the cut-line on the laminate. Then use a router (ideally with a curve-guide attached) to cut the shape. Install and seal the edge with silicone.

Comment: It isn't the cutting the edge I'm worried about, it's about hiding the edge. Usually this is under the skirting boards or with a trim, neither of which is possible with the curved shower tray. Do you think it is OK to just use silicon round the edge then?

Comment: Yes, as long as the bead is smooth right up to and barely over the edge of the laminate. This is common practice when installing a shower pan on a tile floor. Tip: practice with scrap before you install, both for improving your skill and for testing my suggested application.

Comment: Using a piece of cardboard (like the box your laminate came in) is a quick and cheap way to draw and cut a profile to match. If you make a mistake, toss it and try again. Once you've got it exactly right, you can trace the cut edge onto your laminate.